# How to remove specific string

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How can I remove /24 in 9/24/2018?

Comment: Don't forget to give feedback to answers, and accept the answer that best solves your problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT REPLACE('9/24/2018','/24','');
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a general solution, try the following:

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, '9/24/2018'), 105) , 7),'-', '/')
```

or

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, your_date_column), 105) , 7),'-', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some general code that removes whatever text appears between two slashes.

```
set @s = N'Once/upon a time/there were three bears.'

declare @slash1 int = CHARINDEX( '/', @s )
declare @slash2 int = CHARINDEX( '/', @s, @slash1 + 1 )

select substring(@s,1,@slash1) + substring(@s,@slash2+1,len(@s))

-- Result is:  N'Once/there were three bears.'
```